# Problems with submitting a form

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

im having the following problem. A form needs to be submitted and validated, this form is requested at the server and returns a PartialView when the user clicks a button.
When i put a alert in the function, i get the alert once more everytime i click the submitbutton.
So basicly if i have clicked 4 times, the 5th time i click i get 5 alerts.....

```
$(".btnUpdateTopic").click(function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            alert("submit form");
          });
    });
```

i removed all the content of the code to see if there is a problem but even totaly stripped i cannot get it to work properly.

SOLUTION

eventualy i got it to work with this code:

```
$(".btnUpdateTopic").click(function () {
        $("form").submit();
        return false;
    });
        $("form").submit(function () {
            alert("submit form");
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take submit event out of click event and call submit in click event.

```
$(".btnUpdateTopic").click(function () {
    $("form").submit();
});

$("form").submit(function () {
     alert("submit form");
});
```

Comment: I get a download tab when clicking now: "Do you want to open or save UpdateTopic5d74acf4d from localhost?" When putting return false in the methode, i get 2 messages.....